# The minimum of $m,n$ over positive integers such that $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2n(2n-1)}{(2m + 2n)(2m + 2n - 1)}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory

The minimum of $m,n$ over positive integers such that $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2n(2n-1)}{(2m + 2n)(2m + 2n - 1)}$.

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to confirm that when $m=n$ the equation given has no solutions.
And so there are only two cases to consider:

Suppose that $m>n$, then:

$m-n>0$ and 
$2(m+3n)>1$ since $m>1$.

Thus it follows that:

$4(m+3n)>2$ hence $4m-(2-12n)>0$.

And so we can conclude that:

$(m-n)(4m-(2-12n))>0$ which expands to give,

$4m^{2} -12n^{2}+8mn-2m+2n>0$

which we can rearrange to give:

$4m^{2}+4mn-2m+4mn-4n^{2}-2n>8n^{2}-4n$.

Hence:

$(2m+2n)(2m+2n-1)>4n(2n-1)$, noting that the left product is non zero for all positive integers $m,n$.

We then conclude that:

$1>\frac{4n(2n-1)}{(2m+2n)(2m+2n-1)}$ ,hence

$\frac{1}{2}>\frac{2n(2n-1)}{(2m+2n)(2m+2n-1)}$

Now suppose $m<n$, then $m-n<0$, and since $2(m+3n)>1$,

$(m-n)(4m-(2-12n))<0$,

which expands to:

$4m^{2} -12n^{2}+8mn-2m+2n<0$

which rearranging as before forces us to conclude that:

$\frac{1}{2}<\frac{2n(2n-1)}{(2m+2n)(2m+2n-1)}$

Thus there are no positive integer solutions to this equation.